# How to display all failures and error messages in Jmeter html reports- Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, report

I have a question about jmeter reports.
I run my test plan in non ui mode and get csv, and html dashboard in Jmeter.
The problem is in html dashboard that is not informative enough, when I finished the Jmeter run, I enter the csv, and I can see all the steps and all the thread groups and for each step to see if is pass or No, and the error message.
The html dashboard reports not informative, I can see the top 5 errors, but not in which thread group they happened, moreover I want to see all the error and to see exactly where it is failed. Is their a way to display the whole csv as html? since all the reports are for performance and not give data about functional. after the run still need to enter csv and filter success row to failure, and check for error and assertions.
Is their any solution to see in reports the full picture of errors?
** my purpose is that when entering the html report the manual QA can see exactly the errors and in which step and in which thread group, exactly like in the csv. and all of them, without grouping, just the full row data

Provided pic of csv and html dashboard
[[image]][CSV each step get a line with results]

[[image]][dashboard not understand which error occurred in which test and not get full error results]

Answer (score 0):

This "Top 5 errors" is hard-coded so it isn't something you can easily configure. There is `report-template` folder under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation where default report template lives, you can amend [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/index.html) configuration starting from [here](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/bin/report-template/index.html.fmkr#L162)

An easier solution would be switching to [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter) which contains very simplified test report in HTML format with verbose error information on each and every failure, it should be a good substitution for you as manual QAs normally don't need performance-related metrics and charts. See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more detailed explanation and example configuration.

Comment: Hey dimitry, can you please advise how to use the ant with jmeter. in blaze meter mentioned 2 sentences: 1. You can integrate JMeter with Apache Ant using the JMeter Ant Task - how to integrate this task? is it somthing like plug in?    2. "Once you have properly formed an Ant build XML configuration file" - what it means what is properly formed?   3. "you can initiate the JMeter script using Ant"  - what is the script? is it like dahbord report? can you please direct to place where it can be seen step by step this scenarios?

Comment: another question is what it will do? will I still run jmeter with UI? and with command line? did this ant can cause other things not to work?

Comment: You can find a sample Ant `build.xml` script under "extras" folder of your JMeter installation. By default it reads `Test.jmx` file from that folder and creates `Test.html` report there so if you install Ant and just run `ant` in "extras" folder that would be it. No other amendments are required, you  will be able to use JMeter normally

Comment: Hey Dimtri, I download the ant, than I tool my testplan.jmx  and copy it to C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras , than change its name to Test.jtl.    than I entered cmd  -> cd C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras -> ant.

Comment: The results test.html just displayed all the test steps , but not run the testplan.  how can I make ant to actually run it like Jmeter. to perform it?

Comment: You need to rename your test plan to **Test.jmx**

Comment: I changed as you ordered Now it Build failed - C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras.Test.jtl does not exists. that is this file Test.jtl